# How can the HomeController in Spring Batch Admin be replaced

Tags: java, spring, controller, spring-batch-admin

In a Spring Batch Admin environment I use a customized view for "/" and "/home". I do not need the overview of all available endpoints.

I would like to add some more elements to the `model` which is used for the view.

The controller for the endpoints is included in Spring Batch Admin as `org.springframework.batch.admin.web.util.HomeController` ([Source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-admin/blob/master/spring-batch-admin-resources/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/admin/web/util/HomeController.java)). Obviously I cannot just create an own controller and request the mappings because double mappings to the same end points are not allowed in Spring.

The `HomeController` is annotated with `@Controller` and is loaded automatically during initialization.

I have a solution such that I have an own class in the same package which gets higher priority than the one contained in Spring Batch Admin. However, this is not what I prefer as it is bad design IMHO.

This includes an undesired dependency on the implementation of a library. Also, I have to implement the two methods `setDefaultResources` and `setJsonResources` which are called by Batch Admin somehow, which are not interface methods.

I also do not know if the behaviour of having two classes which are the same is even well defined in Java.

**Question**: Is there a simple way to avoid the original home controller from being instantiated or another way to inject my own model into the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to replace the returned model when the root `/` is accessed via an Interceptor. First we have to create our own controller creating the model for our landing page. It is not possible to map it to `/` or `/home` as these mappings are already defined.

```
public class CustomHomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/customHome" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String landingPage(ModelMap model) {
        fill(model);

        // Here "home" refers to a view name e.g. as Freemarker template
        return "home";
    }
}
```

Then, we can intercept all accesses to `/` and replace the model accordingly using an `AsyncHandlerInterceptor`:

```
public class HomeInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    /** The controller instance returning the view for the landing page. */
    private final CustomHomeController customHomeController;

    @Autowired
    public HomeInterceptor(CustomHomeController customHomeController) {
        this.customHomeController = customHomeController;
    }

    /**
     * Swaps the {@link ModelAndView} to the one returned by
     * {@link CustomHomeController#landingPage(ModelMap) }.
     * The controller performs no checking if the model and view is
     * actually one for the landing page. The correct setup
     * has to be ensured by the configuration.
     */
    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        // Manually call the Controller custom home
        // If necessary, also request can be forwarded
        customHomeController.landingPage(modelAndView.getModelMap());
    }
}
```

In the configuration the handler is injected:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/"/>
        <bean class="com.example.HomeInterceptor"/>
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

This requires `xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"` and  `http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd` in the schema definition.

If required, you can then disable the original `/home` mapping via the security configuration.